# FB.ui feed post dialog changes

Tags: facebook, feed, fbdialogs

When a user posts a comment on one of our sites, we give them the option to send the comment to their facebook wall.  i.e. the following code:

```
FB.ui({
    method: "stream.publish",
    attachment: {
        "name": "article title",
        "href": document.location.href,
        "description": "an excerpt from the article"
    }
    message: userComment, // The comment that the user entered on our site
    user_prompt_message: shareText // "What do you think?" or similar, configurable
}, function(response){
    if(response && response.post_id){
        // success!
    }
    else{
        // failed!
    }
});
```

This popped up a dialog with the "your comment here" input pre-filled with the same comment the user posted on our site.  Was totally fine via the [Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy), even officially encouraged at the time we initially put it into place.

But [evidently](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) they deprecated the `message` parameter on July 12th.  So now you get a big "share" box and the content you actually want to share (the user's comment) isn't included anywhere.  So, we're looking for another way to post the user's comment.

So, the [latest documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/) on `stream.publish` still says we can pass the `message` parameter directly via the API call, i.e.

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/stream.publish?callback=derp&message=EABOD+Facebook&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&format=json
```

I tested it and it works, but I'm wondering if it will still work going forward, or if they just haven't shut it down yet?

Answer (score 1):

If it'll replaced, i will be the feed method, which is very similar to streem method.

```
    FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'http://myapp.com/myitem',
        display: 'iframe',
        picture: 'http://myapp.com/mylogo.jpg',
        message: 'my message',
        name: 'click to see item',
        caption: 'title'
    })
```

we will see next major version and see!

Comment: The "message" option gets ignored with the "feed" method too.

Comment: I had to add redirect_uri:.... and next: null, for it to work inside my iframe tab app ... does any1 know why? thanks